# Mongoid Scope Check If Array Field Contains Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mongodb, mongoid

The solution for this question might look pretty simple, but I've been waving around with no answer.

I'm using **Mongoid** in my **Rails 4.1.4** app. I have a model which contains an *Array* field that will house *String* values.

I need a **Mongoid's** *scope* in the model to retrieve those instances where this *Array* field contains a specific *String* value, given as a parameter to the scope. Let's say we have this model:

```
class SomeModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :some_array, type: Array, default: Array.new

  scope :some_scope, ->(value){ elem_match(some_array: value) }

end
```

The above *scope* doesn't work because, obviously, in **MongoDB** *$elemMatch* needs to receive a **Criteria** as the *value*. But, how would be the **Criteria** to just say that the element has to be equal to the given value???.

Any clues on how to write this pretty simple scope???.

Regards!!!. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're drastically overcomplicated things. If a field holds an array then you can search it as though it wasn't an array. For example, if you have this in a document:

```
{ some_array: [ 'where', 'is', 'pancakes', 'house?' ] }
```

and you do a query like this:

```
where(:some_array => 'pancakes')
```

you'll find that document. You don't need [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) or anything complicated here; you can pretend that the array is a single value for simple queries like you have:

```
scope :some_scope, ->(value) { where(:some_array => value) }
```

You only need to get into `$elemMatch` if you want to apply multiple conditions to each element of the array, things like this from the `$elemMatch` docs:

```
   results: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 80, $lt: 85 } }
// ^^^^^^^array           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^multiple conditions
```

Don't feel bad, the current MongoDB docs aren't exactly clear on this stuff (or at least I can't find an explicit explanation).

Comment: Didn't come to my thoughts that it could be that simple. Let me give it a try and I'll let you know if it indeed worked for me. Thanks!.